# NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/EmbeddedValueResolver

Tags: java, spring, maven

I use Maven for developing Spring app. And I've got an error while trying to start my app. I guess the problem is with my POM file. Maybe some dependencies are missed or I put something wrong. Unfortunately I can't understand myself what's wrong.
Here's my AppLoader class:

```
package com.boris.getandsend.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppLoader extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(AppLoader.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(AppLoader.class, args);
}
}
```

Here's my POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<groupId>com.boris</groupId>
<artifactId>GetAndSend</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provide</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.7-dmr</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

And here's the error I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/springframework/beans/factory/config/EmbeddedValueResolver
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.<init>(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:633) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:517) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at com.boris.getandsend.app.AppLoader.main(AppLoader.java:28) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.EmbeddedValueResolver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
... 10 common frames omitted

2017-08-17 22:27:08.708  INFO 2765 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar, file:/Users/boris/Java/GetAndSend/target/classes/, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/gson-2.6.2.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/commons-io-2.5.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-jasper/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-jasper-8.0.33.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.5/ecj-4.5.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.7-dmr/mysql-connector-java-8.0.7-dmr.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.7/mail-1.4.7.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.6/commons-net-3.6.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.0/classmate-1.3.0.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-dbcp2/2.1.1/commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-pool2/2.4.2/commons-pool2-2.4.2.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/boris/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar]
```

Hope you can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some reason my projects have been experiencing a similar issue with Apache File Upload library. The solution was to manually copy the JAR to the deployment directory for the project. I still haven't figured out why this particular JAR is not deployed with the rest. You can add Maven references to your Deployment Assembly in the build path and it should work, but it isn't for me... So I hope it works for you. Otherwise use the manual workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself.
First of all need to use the latest version of spring-boot-starter-parent.
Than need to use this line:
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

as the one below is deprecated:
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

Now everything works.